# Why are only some of the coefficients of my GLM being printed?

Tags: r, glm

I have a GLM with three categorical variables and I want to print the coefficients for each of the levels of the categorical variables however, when I use summary() I only get the coefficients for each of the three categorical variables.

This is my code and the output I get:

```
binmodel2 <- glm(rate ~ age + sex + ID, family = binomial(), data = irlsuicide, weights = pop)
summary(binmodel2)

Call:
glm(formula = rate ~ age + sex + ID, family = binomial(), data = irlsuicide, 
    weights = pop)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-6.6223  -1.1460   0.1466   1.5126   6.7728  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -8.35037    0.05919 -141.088  < 2e-16 ***
age          0.20536    0.01363   15.067  < 2e-16 ***
sex          1.45107    0.04094   35.444  < 2e-16 ***
ID           0.01324    0.00449    2.949  0.00319 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2301.66  on 103  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  506.76  on 100  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1017.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

But I should be getting:

```
Call:
glm(formula = rate ~ age + sex + ID, family = binomial(), data = irlsuicide, 
    weights = pop)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.3382  -0.7672  -0.0952   0.6748   3.3815  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -7.83022    0.08297 -94.371  < 2e-16 ***
age2         0.77568    0.04544  17.069  < 2e-16 ***
age3         0.72427    0.04057  17.851  < 2e-16 ***
age4         0.47303    0.04948   9.561  < 2e-16 ***
sex1         1.44189    0.04095  35.213  < 2e-16 ***
ID2         -0.38530    0.08584  -4.488 7.18e-06 ***
ID3         -0.43499    0.15794  -2.754 0.005884 ** 
ID4         -0.14573    0.14233  -1.024 0.305905    
ID5         -0.55167    0.18199  -3.031 0.002434 ** 
ID6         -0.69006    0.08349  -8.266  < 2e-16 ***
ID7         -0.29398    0.09268  -3.172 0.001513 ** 
ID8         -0.39606    0.10003  -3.959 7.52e-05 ***
ID9         -0.34822    0.09127  -3.815 0.000136 ***
ID10        -0.36341    0.09868  -3.683 0.000231 ***
ID11        -0.15210    0.08645  -1.759 0.078506 .  
ID12        -0.24432    0.08526  -2.866 0.004161 ** 
ID13        -0.29089    0.09057  -3.212 0.001320 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2301.66  on 103  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  163.24  on  87  degrees of freedom
AIC: 699.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like age/sex/id are numeric rather than factor, probably due to how the data was read in.

Comment: Hi! Try using: 
`binmodel2 <- glm(rate ~ I(factor(age)) + I(factor(sex)) + I(factor(ID)), family = binomial(), data = irlsuicide, weights = pop)
summary(binmodel2)`

Comment: But I wouldn't recommend you to do it, because you're only adjusting the mean to each combination of age, sex and ID and your model won't be able to predict new data

Comment: And the t-tests are only saying if, for a given group, assuming normal distribution of the variable, it's mean is different from the global mean

Comment: The comparison's aren't to the global mean, they are to the reference group - an observation with the first value of `age`, `sex` and `ID`.  Also, you don't need `I()` around `factor()` - R will automatically interpret the function `factor()` first.  You would need `I()` to evaluate something that is not a function first e.g., `I(x^2)`.

Comment: Also, the t-tests do not assume normally distributed variables, but normally distributed errors.